# probabilities with copula

Tags: probability, copula

i am trying to calculate the probability of tow random continuous variable being in an interval with the help of copula i am starting with

[image]

i want to calculate it with R but i dont know how to do this double integral

Comment: It isn't clear what you're asking. If you are asking for R code for double integrals, that would be off topic here. Can you clarify this?

Comment: i fact i am not sure if my equation is correct, and i am wondering if there is a better way to write this integral a simpler one without any integrale

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the definition of copula:

$$P(U \le b, V \le d) = C(b,d)$$

to calculate this.

$$P(a \le U \le b, c \le V\le d) = P(a \le U \le b, V \le d) - P( a \le U \le b, V \le c).$$

The first term is

$$P(a \le U \le b, V \le d) = P(U \le b, V \le d) - P(U \le a, V \le d)$$ and the second term is
$$P( a \le U \le b, V \le c) = P(U \le b, V \le c) - P(U \le a, V \le c)$$

so overall you have

$$P(a \le U \le b, c \le V\le d) = (C(b,d) - C(a,d)) - (C(b,c) - C(a,c))$$

This probability is also called the $C$--volume of the rectangle $[a,b] \times [c,d]$, and of course it is what you get when you do the double integral in the usual way (using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus twice). See Defintion 2.1 in Nelsen's Introduction to Copulas [here](http://w4.stern.nyu.edu/ioms/docs/sg/seminars/nelsen.pdf).